# Class method 'XXX' object has no attribute 'xxx' Error

Tags: python, class, methods

I have searched all over and can't find the reason why? I'm trying to run this code (it's from the Udacity Initiate Programming on Python Lesson 6):

```
import media

toy_story = media.Movie("Toy Story",
                        "A story of a boy and his toys that come back to life",
                        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/13/Toy_Story.jpg/220px-Toy_Story.jpg",
                        "https://youtu.be/KYz2wyBy3kc",
                        "4 Stars")

avatar = media.Movie("Avatar",
                     "A Marine on an Alien Planet",
                     "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/b0/Avatar-Teaser-Poster.jpg/220px-Avatar-Teaser-Poster.jpg",
                     "https://youtu.be/5PSNL1qE6VY",
                     "5 Stars")

# print(toy_story.storyline)
avatar.show_trailer()
```

Which is successfully using the Class Movie on the file media.py on the same folder with the following code and it's creating the Movie objects just fine:

```
import webbrowser

class Movie():
    def __init__(self, movie_title, movie_storyline, movie_poster, movie_trailer, movie_rating):
        self.title = movie_title
        self.storyline = movie_storyline
        self.poster = movie_poster
        self.trailer = movie_trailer
        self.rating = movie_rating

    def show_trailer(self):
        webbrowser.open(self.trailer)
```

However, whenever I try to run the first code I get an error that says:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-44-50b40b5dbf08> in <module>()
     14 
     15 # print(toy_story.storyline)
---> 16 avatar.show_trailer()

AttributeError: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'show_trailer'
```

I have tried many things, have read about indentation but it's fine, have even written it down again from scratch to flawlessly indent the code, have added the `@classmethod` on top of the method `show_trailer()` tried it as a function with a `return` statement, and even running it through `python -tt media.py` nothing works.

I know the course was designed for Python 2 but thought it would be an additional challenge to understand it and then go figure out how to do it on Python 3, at which I succeeded until now =(.

Help!

Comment: Why would you make `show_trailer` a `@classmethod` and then try to call it on an instance, `avatar`? Clearly one of those two things is wrong (and probably the first one).

Comment: Anyway, are you sure you only have one file called `media.py` on your path? Try `print(media.__file__)` after the `import media`, and make sure that what it prints out is the path to the file you're editing.

Comment: Also, can you provide a link to the code you're porting from Python 2 so we don't have to search for it?

Comment: Your code works as you posted it, in both Python 2 and 3. I suspect an incorrect indent -- maybe mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: @abarnert just following the exercise, there's more efficient ways for sure, the point is probably trying to shows us it can be done.

Comment: Nobody's asked you anything about efficiency. Why are you bringing that up?

Comment: @abarnert as suggested: 

C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\media.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-9959cea24cb0> in <module>()
---> 17 avatar.show_trailer()

AttributeError: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'show_trailer'

All the files are on that same path

This is the [link](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud036/lessons/997889780/concepts/10136290690923).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev after reseraching a lot that was my first thought, but I have tried fixing indentations manually, starting from scratch and still same error.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Since your code works as you posted it here, try copy-pasting from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the beginning I was using Atom and the Hydrogen Plugin to Run the .py's which was the problem, the code runs perfectly on Python's IDLE.

I'll research on why but my guess is that Atom + Hydrogen might not be the best combination to code.

The issue is solved, Code does work.